# dropdown width different on different systems

Tags: asp.net

I have 3 textboxes and a dropdown. In some machines the dropdown is appearing larger than the textboxes. The textboxes are appearing correct in all machines but its just the dropdown width is not coming correct.

Comment: Could you post the html?  Are you setting the width explicitly, through an inline style or an external css sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Is that your requirement? Because, by default dropdowns width is slightly bigger than textbox width.